# jquery :gt issue.. trying to show more

Tags: jquery

NI am trying to have a news area on a site.. each item is contained in its own div class called .newsitem. I want to be able to click .showmorenews to show an additional item. What am i doing wrong? I can't figure it out and I'm fairly new to jquery. Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var remixnewsshow = 2;
    remixnewsshow--; //fix variable since the index for :gt starts at 0
    $(".newsitem:gt(" + remixnewsshow + ")").hide();
    $(".showmorenews").click(function () {
        remixnewsshow++;
        $(".newsitem:gt(" + remixnewsshow + ")").show(); 
    });
});
```

html:

```
                <div class="box-news">
                    <h3>Recent News</h3>
                    <div class="newsitem">
                        <span class="month">Jan</span>
                        <span class="day">16</span>
                        <span class="news">Text text text</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="newsitem">
                        <span class="month">Jan</span>
                        <span class="day">2</span>
                        <span class="news">Text text text</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="newsitem">
                        <span class="month">Oct</span>
                        <span class="day">3</span>
                        <span class="news">Text Text Text</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="showmorenews"><a href="#blank">View Another News Item</a></div>
                </div>
```

Comment: What's it doing and what do you want it to do? Looking at your code it should show the first two news items and then one more every time you click showmorenews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is actually to change the 2nd `gt` to `eq`:

```
 $(".showmorenews").click(function () {
        remixnewsshow++;
        $(".newsitem:eq(" + remixnewsshow + ")").show(); 
    });
```

The problem with what you were doing is that you were initially showing 2 elements, then when clicked you would show all elements greater than 2, which is all the rest.  You just want to show the next single element.

Comment: That works great! Thank You! My first question on here.. answered in less than a minute! Amazing!